# NodeJS error when I require inside module._compile

Tags: javascript, module, compilation

I'm learning how NodeJS's `require()` function works to better understand the node ecosystem.

I wrote a script that uses module._compile to compile a script.  When I try to `require()` within the string, it balks... but it seems to have the right paths.  What am I doing wrong?

I guess it's worth mentioning I have the `json3` module installed in the same directory in `./node_modules/`.

**The Script**

I wrote this script, which works--until I uncomment the line that's marked.

```
"use strict";

var json3 = require('json3');

console.log("require.main.filename:", require.main.filename);
console.log("require.main:", require.main);

var module = new module.constructor();
module._compile(`
"use strict";

console.log("require.main.filename:", require.main.filename);
console.log("require.main:", require.main);

// When I uncomment this, it breaks.  Why?
//var json3 = require('json3');

module.exports = {
  run: function () { console.log("It works!") }
};
`, require.main.paths[0]);

module.exports.run();
```

**Script Output**

Here's the output (when the problem code is commented out).

```
require.main.filename: /home/user/tmp/tmp.js
require.main: Module {
  id: '.',
  exports: {},
  parent: null,
  filename: '/home/user/tmp/tmp.js',
  loaded: false,
  children: 
   [ Module {
       id: '/home/user/tmp/node_modules/json3/lib/json3.js',
       exports: [Object],
       parent: [Circular],
       filename: '/home/user/tmp/node_modules/json3/lib/json3.js',
       loaded: true,
       children: [],
       paths: [Array] } ],
  paths: 
   [ '/home/user/tmp/node_modules',
     '/home/user/node_modules',
     '/home/node_modules',
     '/node_modules' ] }
require.main.filename: /home/user/tmp/tmp.js
require.main: Module {
  id: '.',
  exports: {},
  parent: null,
  filename: '/home/user/tmp/tmp.js',
  loaded: false,
  children: 
   [ Module {
       id: '/home/user/tmp/node_modules/json3/lib/json3.js',
       exports: [Object],
       parent: [Circular],
       filename: '/home/user/tmp/node_modules/json3/lib/json3.js',
       loaded: true,
       children: [],
       paths: [Array] } ],
  paths: 
   [ '/home/user/tmp/node_modules',
     '/home/user/node_modules',
     '/home/node_modules',
     '/node_modules' ] }
```

Why won't the module within the *ad hoc* module load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So two things in your code. When you do

```
var module = new module.constructor();
```

You loose the original module object, you shouldn't do that. Next to know what the exact issue is, you should have set environment variable `NODE_DEBUG=module`. This will give you what happens in background. Doing that you get an import message

```
MODULE 11063: looking for "json3" in []
```

This means there are no paths set for module loading. So you should add the paths also. Below is the updated code

```
"use strict";

var json3 = require('json3');
var os = require("os");
console.log("require.main.filename:", require.main.filename);
console.log("require.main:", require.main);

var _module = new module.constructor();
_module.paths = module.paths;

_module._compile(`
"use strict";

// console.log("require.main.filename:", require.main.filename);
// console.log("require.main:", require.main);

//When I uncomment this, it breaks.  Why?
var json3 = require('json3');

module.exports = {
  run: function () { console.log("It works!") }
};
`, __dirname + "/dynamic_code_loaded_at_run_time.js");

_module.exports.run();
```

Also the second parameter of `_compile` is the filename which is being loaded, so you should not provide it a path but a filename. And now you get the correct output

```
It works!
```

Comment: In the end, this gave me everything I needed.  Thanks!  In case anyone coming here is also interested, you can add variables to the module as you would expect:  outside the module use _module.stuff = mystuff; and inside the module access it with module.stuff;